# Where do I find my logs if I no filename is given

Tags: python, logging

I am using Python's logging module to log, what is the default location my logs will go to if I don't give the filename.

I have configured like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I cannot explicitly mention `filename`.

Comment: By default the log will go to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll write to stderr by default, which will be the console window if you haven't redirected it externally.

Comment: So, it will not be written to any file?

Comment: No, it will not. You have to provide `filename` as a parameter to the basicConfig for that to happen. You mentioned you couldn't mention filename, so maybe you could provide it to your program as a console parameter or redirect stderr directly from the command line. For example, in bash: `python program.py 2> path_to_log_file`.